# "Insert before" for std::list

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a linked list which contains the following:

1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2

now lets say I wish to convert this to:

1, 10, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 2, 3, 10, 2

i.e. insert 10 before all 2's.

How should I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::list<>::insert()`?

Comment: @iccthedral http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/

Comment: @tenfour Won't I invalidate the iterator?

Comment: @Baz: [*all of the previously obtained iterators and references remain valid after the insertion and refer to the same elements they were referring before*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/insert/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Off the top of my head

```
for (std::list<int>::iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i)
  if (*i == 2)
     l.insert(i, 10);
```

Simple enough. You don't need to worry about iterator invalidation because `insert` on a `std::list` does not invalidate any iterators. It's one of the advantages of using `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
auto it = l.begin();
while ((it = std::find(it, l.end(), 2)) != l.end())
{
    it = l.insert(it, 10);
    std::advance(it, 2);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I like `<algorithm>`'s manifesto but I'm voting for the guy with the `for` loop.

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually, so would I... :)

Answer (score 0):

create a structure with node and info like

```
struct test{

int info;
int *node;

}
```

you can refer them as test->info and test->node

now try something like this .

```
while(end_of_list){

list[index]=2;

create a new structure object(new_struct) .

new_struct->info=10;
new_struct->node=node_containing_2.

previous_node_to_2->node=new_struct.

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while(item != NULL)
{
if(item->intval == 2)
{
Item *newitem = (Item *) malloc(sizeof(Item));
newitem->intval = 10;
prev->next = newitem;
newitem->next = item;
}
prev = item;
item = item->next;
}
```

If you made your own linked list.
Also off the top of my head, and c style.

Comment: This is not C++ (or C either), and he said he's using `std::list`.

Comment: Didn't read he was using std::list yet, and what is not C about this code ?

Comment: @Minion91: Non-C things about it include typos `while{` and `MULL`, use of `new`, Java-style use of `Item` both as the type of a list node and as the type of a variable that indirects to a list node, use of the keyword `int` as the name of a struct member.

Comment: Edited for c conformity, btw what is wrong with using Item item ?

Comment: Should be `Item *newItem = ...`

Comment: In any case this is not a good solution; there is really no scenario where you would want to mix all this into a single function. In C you still want to have a `list_insert()` function of some kind which is separate from the OP's specific problem.